# How can I preview files in the browser with aptana studio 3 like I can with dreamweaver

Tags: browser, localhost, aptana, dreamweaver, preview

I basically want to preview them directly.
How do I do this please?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me : where do you specify the ".php" extension when you're asked to provide : Base, URL and Document Root when configuring a Simple or External Web Server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preview files in Aptana Studio 3, you need to configure your web server in **Preferences/Aptana/Web Servers**. After that, Preview toolbar button should be ready to use.

for example : IF your file is *.php*, then configure the extention *.php*  in **Preferences/Aptana/Web Servers**